# Issue initializing a JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to initialize a JSONObject with the following string, received from a web service:

```
"{
    "campaignid": "8",
    "campaignname": "Pilotarienak 2011",
    "campaignlink": "http:\\/\\/www.xxx.com\\/fr\\/cote-basque\\/agenda\\/2011-05-20\\/FMAAQU064FS016DV-pilotarienak-d-anglet?fromapp",
    "splash": "http:\\/\\/www.xxx.com\\/ads\\/customers\\/pilotarienak\\/320x480.jpg",
    "banner": "http:\\/\\/www.xxx.com\\/ads\\/customers\\/pilotarienak\\/320x160.jpg"
}"
```

It seems to be valid json (it validates in jsonlint.com), but when initializing a JSONObject with that I get:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Anybody can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to instantiate it from a String with extra quotes. You need to remove the wrapping quotes(I'm not using your string, but giving an example to make it clearer):

This is OK:

```
String jStr= "{\"param1\":\"hello\"}";
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jStr);
```

This is not:

```
String jStr= "\"{\"param1\":\"hello\"}\"";
//  note this ^^             and this ^^ 
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite all, in a simplified mode (just for test). I think that you put some invalid character.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove All the "\" caracters